# Has Krishna said anywhere that he took avatara only for Arjun?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna

Krishna has [explicitly mentioned in Mahabharata](https://histonerd.com/when-krishna-met-arjuna-for-the-first-time/) that he liked Arjun the most and that he wouldn't stay on earth even for a moment without Arjun.

> My wives, my kinsmen, my relatives, none amongst these is dearer to me than Arjuna. O Daruka, **I shall not be able to cast my eyes, even for a single moment, on the earth bereft of Arjuna**” said Krishna to his charioteer Daruka, as he was preparing for the upcoming battle of the 14th day of Kurukshetra war

Interestingly Krishna and Arjun took birth on the same day.
Has he said anywhere in Mahabharata that he took birth only for Arjun ?
Also as soon as Krishna died, Arjun lost all his powers.

Comment: Shyam said this for Arjun ? I thought Madhav loved Radha Rani the most ? Taking this personally cause that’s my namesake  Me & Rukmini, gonna go on strike coz I can’t handle this Jokes aside, I don’t know the answer to this question. I know Mohan & Arjun were Nar & Narayan in past life (though that is obviously figurative too) And Karn was some kind of bad guy doing stuff to pandits which is why he got so messed up treatment in his life, given up for adoption by Kunti, inaccurate caste and prejudice, couldn’t get training, then ended up as Duryodhan’s comrade.

Comment: Was just joking @river And I think Radha Rani & Rukmini are both the same in figurative meaning, both are Lakshmi. That’s what I was taught.