# Does Krishna love Radha?

Tags: krishna, radha

Does Krishna love Radha ? If yes, then why did he romance with other women also ? While Krishna has [mentioned explicitly that Arjun](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/53824/23709) is extremely dear to him.
Has Krishna mentioned anything like this about Radha ?

Has Krishna mentioned anywhere directly or indirectly that he loves Radha ?

Comment: First thing first is How do you define "love" ? What is romance? Whom are we comparing? are they mere mortals? or some fictional characters? Or are they the Divine themselves?

Comment: @Rāmachandra Parvati got angry when [she was informed](https://www.voot.com/shows/shrimad-bhagwat-mahapuran/1/801327/a-story-of-true-love-and-sorrow/807276) that Shiva was dancing with some other woman. (The other woman was actaually Sati who had died)
And shiva got extremely depressed when Sati died.

Comment: @river don't believe in whatever they show in the tv series. Read the authentic books.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I know many tv series are not authentic but writer of this show was criticisizing shows that show factually incorrect things. This is why I am referencing this show. Also presently I am reading mbh which will take lot of time to read. Purans are later on my reading list. Reading hindu scriptures takes years, in the meantime I am asking doubts.

Comment: @river Like I commented in your other post, this question as well is not well researched.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I think questions needn't be well researched , that is for answers. Also everyone knows that Krishna romanced Gopis apart from Radha. I am just asking if Krishna has said anywhere that he loves (romantic love) Radha or not , like he has said about Arjun (friendly love).

Comment: mention (from krishna) needn't be explicit, it can also be from action from Krishna like Krishna crying for Radha or something like that.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto IMO one thing is sure Krishna loves Arjun (or his bhakts) more than Lakshmi. As he has mentioned he loves Arjun more than his wives and one of his wife is Rukmini who is avatara of Lakshmi.

Comment: @river dear fellow Sadhaka, Qns have to be well re-searched for the simple reason of mutual respect.Many illustrious scholars of scriptures are on our community who are ready to help and answer insightful Qns.They take out some of their precious time to enlighten us with their superior wisdom and help us selflessly so it is our duty to present a well-researched Qn that genuinely displays our curiosity and humble attitude towards learning more about Sanatana dharma.A well-researched Qn also makes it easier for the scholar to answer accurately and to the point and saves his time too!

Comment: Being inferior to you in experience of this site, i would like to ask for forgiveness if my words seem too imposing and rude perhaps.I do not wish to insult you but just wanted to uphold respect for the scholars who put their precious time into helping others here....

Comment: Agree with @TheLittleNaruto that your Qn isn't well-researched as you don't even have your definitions right.I would be really grateful if you could add some research of your own(searching and reading articles, blogposts(suggest reading articles from iskcondesiretree, iskcon yt channel, other gaudiya acharyas like Swami Mukundananda etc), reframe the Qn and then humbly request the community members if they could kindly take a look at it!(I know this may feel imposing but w/o mutual respect this site holds no meaning....)

Comment: @Rāmachandra I fail to understand how is asking if Krishna has mentioned directly or indirectly (through his action ) that he loves Radha a wrong question.  Krishna has mentioned that Arjun is extremely dear to him . I am just asking if he has mentioned such thing about Radha or not. That is simple question.

Comment: Where did i mention the Qn is wrong? Well-researched yes. You still didn't answer my basic Qns on definitions.What is love? Who is Radha? Who is Krishna? wha kind of relationship did they share? Who are the Gopis? Research abt them a bit i am sure you will get closer to your actual Qn then and shun all unnecessary details!