# Who was the dearest person to Ram?

Tags: ramayana, rama

In Krishna avatar, [Arjun was dearest](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/53824/has-krishna-said-anywhere-that-he-took-avatara-only-for-arjun) to Krishna.

In Ram avatar,who was the dearest ?

Answer (score 1):

The dearest to Rama is Lakshmana -

> "Of what use to me is the recovery of Seetha or even life itself,
> since my brother now lying, before my eyes, has been struck down in
> the fight? **It can be possible, if I were to look for her, to find a
> consort equal to Seetha in this world of mortals but not a brother, a
> friend and a comrade in a hostile war, such as Lakshmana**!

- Sarga 49, Yuddha kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.

> My energy to fight is failing, even as I see **this valiant Lakshmana,
> who is dearer to me than life,** bathed in blood, my mind being
> greatly disturbed.

- Sarga 101, Yuddha kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.